# How to control Docker Image Version using Terraform while pushing images to ECR

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ecr

I am new to Terraform so please be kind.

During Build process, Terraform is pushing the docker image to AWS ECR with a new name with every build.

As Image Name is different, we need to create a new Task Definition for each new build.

Is there a way to handle this issue in Terraform?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to replace the task definition each time with the new image, then you can update the image name used in the task definition and Terraform will handle the update for you.

If you need to generate a new task definition each time and leave the old ones in place then read on..

If you do not need to keep the task definition in the Terraform state, then you could remove it after deployment so that next time a new one will be created.

The state rm command removes a resource from the state:

`terraform state rm aws_ecs_task_definition.service`

If you do need to keep each task definition in the Terraform state, you could create a data source for which you can use the `for_each` operator to generate a collection of resources for.

As an example you could save the container definitions of each task definition to a JSON file within a folder. Each file looks something like this:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "a-service",
    "image": "my-image",
    "cpu": 10,
    "memory": 512,
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Use the fileset function to list files in the folder and generate a new resource for each file using `for_each`:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service" {
  family                = "service"
  for_each              = fileset(path.module, "task-definitions/*.json")
  container_definitions = file("${path.module}/${each.key}")
}
```